# Notation inquiry when proving statements about a function restricted to different subsets of its defined domain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I recently carried out a proof that required some tedious notation, so I was hoping the S.E. community could offer some input on how I could "make my life easier".

Specifically, the proof leads with the following definition of a function $f$:

> $f: A \overset{1-1}\longrightarrow B$

The other relevant information is as follows:

1. $B \subseteq A$
2. Informally, we define the function $f^n: A \rightarrow A$ by iterating $f$ $n$ times. $f^0$ is the identify function $I_A$.
3. $H_n=f^n[A]\setminus f^n[B]$

The aim of the proof was to demonstrate that, "**...$f$ maps $H_n$ bijectively onto $H_{n+1}$**".

The way I attempted to formalize this claim was as follows:

$\forall n \in \omega \big ( f \upharpoonright H_n: H_n \xrightarrow[onto]{1-1} H_{n+1}\big)$, which is a straightforward induction proof...and, as a side note, for any $n$, $H_n \subseteq A$...so $f$ is defined on these sets.

However, when trying to prove the surjectivity (*onto*) claim, I would write the following statement:

> Prove that $f\upharpoonright H_n[H_n]=H_{n+1}$

The even more tediuous way of writing this is if you express $H_n$ and $H_{n+1}$ in its full form to yield the following statement:

> Prove $f \upharpoonright f^n[A]\setminus f^n[B] \Big [f^n[A]\setminus f^n[B] \Big]=f^{n+1}[A]\setminus f^{n+1}[B]$

**I wondered if there was a cleaner convention to write such statements.**

---

In my book *The Foundations of Mathematics* by Kenneth Kunen, the following definition is given:

$F[A]=\text{ran}(F\upharpoonright A)$

Using that definition, it would seem as though $f\upharpoonright H_n[H_n]=\text{ran}(f\upharpoonright H_n \upharpoonright H_n)$

The syntax "$f\upharpoonright H_n \upharpoonright H_n$" is a little weird...but I am guessing that this effectively defaults to simply "$f\upharpoonright H_n$".

Therefore, it seems like the following is true:

$f\upharpoonright H_n[H_n]=\text{ran}(f\upharpoonright H_n \upharpoonright H_n)=\text{ran}(f\upharpoonright H_n)=f[H_n]$

So instead of using "$f\upharpoonright H_n[H_n]$", I should instead (for notational convenience) use "$f[H_n]$" and simply remember that whatever I prove is ***specific*** to "$f$ when its domain is $H_n$".

**Is this the standard convention that I should use?** Or is there a better/preferred one?

Comment: What do you mean $f: A \overset{1-1}\longrightarrow B$? Do you mean $f$ is $1-1$? But if $B$ is a proper subset of $A$ this is impossible.

Comment: @cookiesandmilk yes, that notation means that $f$ is injective. And no, I do not believe that is true. Consider the mapping $n \mapsto n^2$ defined on the natural numbers.